# error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate in TKinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm getting a very unhelpful error message whenever I click on a menu option in TKinter:

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

The problem is, it's intermittent, it happens about every five or six attempts to click on a menu item, and there's no line numbers or anything that could point me in the right direction. The codebase for the program is very large, and since I don't know which part of the code is causing it, I don't know what to share to try to find the root cause.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434408/fatal-python-error-pyeval-restorethread-null-tstate) says it can be fixed by updating gtk, but I'm not using gtk at all. I'm using Python 2.7, tkinter version 8.5, and running on windows. If anyone knows how I can fix this, or even where I can try to find the offending code, I would appreciate it.

If you're okay with poring over thousands of lines of code, here's the [GitHub](https://github.com/digiholic/universalSmashSystem) and the file that loads the [TKinter code](https://github.com/digiholic/universalSmashSystem/blob/master/builder/builderWindow.py)

Comment: Does your program use threads?

Comment: Not intentionally. I'm assuming TKinter does under the hood, but I've never explicitly done any thread stuff in my own code.